# AutoCompleteTextView set Text not working in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-application

I know this is common to ask but,I tried most resources on the internet and it doesn't work for me, Can anyone how can I achieve this problem?
When I setOntext on my `AutoCompleteTextView` The list did not display, When I tried setting the `Male` value of `AutoCompleteTextView` the `Female` did not show only the `Male` value shown.

[image]

**Myjavafile**

```
 spinSex = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSex);
 String[] Sex = new String[]{"MALE", "FEMALE"};
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSex = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Sex);
    adapterSex.setDropDownViewResource(simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinSex.setAdapter(adapterSex);
    spinSex.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
      public void run() {
       spinSex.setText("MALE");
       spinSex.showDropDown();

  }
}, 10);
```

**Xml**

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
       android:id="@+id/spinnerSex"
       android:layout_width= "match_parent"
       android:hint="Sex"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
```

**Updated :** I tried this but when I use `spinSex.setSelection(spinnerSex);` the error says

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (1 ... 1) ends beyond length 0
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
String gender ="FEMALE";
    new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             adapterSex = (ArrayAdapter) spinSex.getAdapter();
                int spinnerSex = adapterSex.getPosition(gender);
                spinSex.setSelection(spinnerSex);

    }
  },
    500);
```

Comment: Because "FEMALE:" is not start with "MA". You can customize `Filter` in `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: @GHH Yes I am aware but How can I display `FEMALE` after setting the default value which is `MALE`

Answer (score 1):

Can use this and will work

autoCompleteTextView.setText("what ever you want to show", false)